# Recursive solution to Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic Programming and Knapsack Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626854/dynamic-programming-and-knapsack-application)

I have been trying to understand Dynamic Programming but with each new problem I get a bit confused over how to write recursion for it.

Take the following problem:
There  is  an  L × H  metal  sheet  which  can  be  cut  by  a  machine  into  two  pieces  either  vertically  or horizontally.Both  L, H    are  integral  and  the  cuts  also  happen  along  integral  values.There  are  n rectangular  patterns  l(i) × h(i) ,   i  ≤  n  (l  , h are  also  integral)  where  the  i-th  pattern  has  proﬁt  c(i).  Design  an  eﬃcient  algorithm  to cut the sheet in a way so as to maximize  the total  proﬁt.

Now I think for solving it we would create a table of LxH (which would be filled diaganally). But how do we form a recursion for solving this problem ?

Comment: You should start with a recursive O(2^n) solution and look at how to optimize it into a polynomial solution, rather than doing the opposite.

Comment: @jli how do I start approaching this problem ?

Comment: Same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626854/dynamic-programming-and-knapsack-application)

Comment: A dynamic programming problem can be solved using recursion by definition, as each instance that's not a base case can be solved using dynamic programming and some extra steps. What makes this different from recursion is not clear. Are you sure this isn't homework?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like for every T(L, H), verify the best alternative between:

- collect the profit right away
- cut every possible way horizontally
- cut every possible way vertically

Something like:

```
T(L, H) = max(
    c(L, H),  
    T(i, H)+T(L-i, H), // 0<i<L
    T(L, i)+T(L, H-i)  // 0<i<H
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why do you really want to use recursion while you have a dp-relation. Backtracking-recursion is often very-inefficient as its complexity is usually O(2^N) or higher.

However, those exponential algorithms are much like this:

```
function rec(state)
    if state = end
       return
    Choose the current element
    rec(state + 1)
    Don't choose the current element
    rec(state + 1)
```

In your case this maybe something like this brute-force:

```
  function rec(rect r)
      if r is empty
        return 0
      Max = 0
      for i = 1 to r.width
          for j = 1 to r.hight
             rect g = cut(r, i, j)
             Max = max(Max, profit(g) + rec(r - g))
      return Max
```